# Automatically restarting a process when it dies?

Tags: process, raspberry-pi, monitoring, background-process, nohup

I have a process running on a raspberry pi.  After ssh ing into in to the process is started like this:

```
nohup .../blah/blah &
```

IIUC this allows me to log out of the pi and the process keeps running.  However it dies sometimes, and I have to log in and manually restart it.  Is there a way to monitor it and have it restart itself?

Comment: For a more permanent solution, you could consider creating a systemd service for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run it in an infinite loop:

```
#!/bin/sh

while true; do
    .../blah/blah
done
```

This would be a script that you start with `nohup` in the background. When `blah` dies, it is immediately restarted, until the script is killed.

A variation that ends the loop if a file called `stopme` appears in the working directory of the script (a check is only made before (re-)starting `blah`):

```
#!/bin/sh

while true; do
    [ -e stopme ] && break
    .../blah/blah
done
```

Comment: what if the script is killed ?

Comment: @neobie The question is about trying to restart a process that sometimes dies, probably because it's buggy, not about restarting something that is getting killed. If the script dies, then the user killed it. They could then easily restart it. If that is a real concern for you, then set up a cron job to do the same thing, or modify the original process to run as a systemd service, instead of running this trivial script.